# Javascript one variable is not accessible

Tags: javascript

I have variable "a" and variable "cm", both declared in the same scope.
But inside each loop, variable a is accessible, while cm is not accessible:

```
var a = [];
var sm = grid.getSelectionModel();
var cm = grid.getColumnModel();
Ext.each(sm.getSelections(), function (item, index) {
  var s = 'test';

  a.push(s); //it works, a is accessible
  var colHeader = cm.getColumnHeader(index); //Uncaught ReferenceError: cm is not defined
});
```

why? How can I access cm inside each loop?

This is documentation of grid.getColumnModel:
[ExtJsGrid](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/source/GridPanel.html#Ext-grid-GridPanel-method-getColumnModel)

Comment: is sm.getSelections() result has grid.getColumnModel()'s inside it ? Could you be changing cm indirect way?

Comment: It's not possible based on what you've shown us.

Comment: `cm` doesn't have `getColumnHeader()` from above code

Comment: We dont know the structure of grid.getSelectionModel() and grid.getColumnModel() methods result.

Comment: Does it say "is not defined" or "is undefined"?

Comment: I have add link to documentation.
Bergi it is: "is not defined"

Comment: inside loop just check for cm , console.log(cm) , later you can see what is present inside cm and access it accordingly

Comment: can't check: Uncaught ReferenceError: cm is not defined

Answer (score 0):

`cm` should be accessible in the code that you gave. You can verify that by doing `console.log(cm);` right before you get the error.

The issue is most likely that the `getColumnHeader` function doesn't exist on `cm`.

Comment: cm is not accessible:
Uncaught ReferenceError: cm is not defined.